# Fox DHX2 servicing, Need advice on oil

Tags: suspension, full-suspension, fox

looks like DHX2 2021 runs with 4wt oil. If I top it up with 5wt? How silly it would be? Need it done asap so just looking for shortcuts...
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You’ll change the tuning of the damper so that it runs slightly slower by mixing in the 5wt oil. The viscosity will be an averaged value of the two.

Technically you shouldn’t mix brands of oil to do this but it sounds like you’re needing a quick fix.

You should be able to do this until you can get some more 4wt to replace the entire volume in the damper.